# Input separator of the `read` builtin in Bash

Tags: bash, read

Given such situation:

```
echo "Please enter your name"
read name    # user enters: john smith
echo $name   # prints: john
```

What could cause `read` to read only the first word of the input?
Is there a shell variable that controls this?

I came across this in a [question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556300/using-the-read-command-to-store-multiple-words-in-one-variable) and I'm wondering how to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: It has to have something to do with multiple fields - `$IFS` or filename generation. But `echo` concats on spaces - and so even for multiple args they should come together. I can imagine if it was an extra quote level deep - like an ssh script or something it might lose some - but that's fuzzy. `echo` should at least print the args unless `$IFS` is composed of all of the alphabetics or something. `printf`, on the other hand, would only print *john* or *123* in that scenario, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to accept whatever the user enters, use this form

```
IFS= read -r name
```

That will accept leading/trailing/inner spaces as well as literal backslashes.